# What is the single word for "suppression of one's right by using muscle power" or "not letting one exercise one's power by using force"

Tags: adjectives, single-word-requests

Is there any single word for **"suppression of one's right by using muscle power"** or **"not letting one exercise one's power by using force"**?

Comment: Can you give an example sentence that would contain the word?  As things stand, something simple like "force" or "coerece" or "compel" would answer the question.

Comment: A dictionary will show that perhaps the default sense of _suppression_ itself is 'suppression of people's human rights by the use of force'. A thesaurus will suggest other possible terms (if there are any).